# column to datetime pandas with rolling time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that has a timestamp column that looks like:

```
0:40:40
0:40:45 
...

23:59:55
0:00:00
0:00:05 
...
```

And repeats like this for many days. How can this be converted into a datetime object with a different consecutive day assigned to each new day? Currently, the `to_datetime` assigns them all to the same day.

Answer (score 0):

after making the DATE column with to_datetime :

```
df['New_date'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['DATE']+datetime.timedelta(days=row.name), axis=1)
```

NB: row.name to add the index number as a day

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
days = 0 
for i in range(2, size + 1): 
    if df.at[i - 1, 'timestamp'].hour > df.at[i, 'timestamp'].hour:
        days += 1
    df.at[i, 'timestamp'] += datetime.timedelta(days=days)
```